# jQuery Ajax 404 under embedded Edge (Office taskpane)

Tags: javascript, jquery, office-js, microsoft-edge

I'm creating an Office Add-In, which will mostly be run on the **desktop**. I'm testing it using the **Edge DevTools** as Office hosts an embedded MS Edge view which the plugin runs inside.

I'm making an Ajax call using **jQuery** to our existing Web Server to log in - this will have a username and password and will return back a login token. However, when I try to run this call, I get a `404 error`. I can't reproduce this anywhere else other than the Office Add-in, even navigating to the add-in's address in a browser like Chrome makes the call work normally.

As an example, consider the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://my.webserver.address/API/Login",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: '{"Email": "user@example.com", "Password": "Ex@mp13P@ssw0rd"}',
    success: data => {
        debugger;
        //handle response
    }
})
```

Running this snippet in Chrome will call the API, and hit the `debugger` inside the success with a valid response. However, running this exact same snippet under the Office Add-in will throw me a 404 error:

`HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). (XHR)OPTIONS - https://my.webserver.address/API/Login`

I would attempt to test this in full MS Edge, but I don't have a way to do that due to having already upgraded to the new 'Edgium' Edge. I know that MS is planning to drop Edge early next year (2021), however I haven't seen anything about what will happen to the embedded Edge inside Office.

Is this a known issue with Edge? I haven't been able to find many reports of this happening outside of a few situations where people hadn't turned off Edge's loopback isolation, but that was their solution. I already have that set up - running the commands given changes nothing.

Comment: is it a post API? if you get result while calling this in chrome, it looks like a get API.
if we have he API code, it will be more helpful

Comment: This is a POST API. Unfortunately I can't post the API-side code other than maybe the declaration, but I can tell you it is a POST request that's made to the API which is running under an ASP.NET server. I can also tell you that the API doesn't get hit when one tries to call via Edge - it does in Chrome though.

Comment: If you want to make a test with the Edge legacy browser then you can try to refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-sysupdate-access-old-edge). It can help you run the Edge legacy and Edge Chromium browser side by side. You can test it there and let us know about the results. It may help to narrow down the issue. If possible then try to provide the detailed steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: As per the linked document: "Starting with Windows 10 version 20H2 Microsoft Edge Legacy is no longer included. Starting with this version of Windows 10 the side-by-side experience is not supported.". I'm on Windows 10 20H2 already. Is there a way to install Edge on 20H2? It's obviously still included in some form due to being used in Office, but following the instructions given to allow it to be run side-by-side still keeps me on Edgium.

Comment: Microsoft provides free virtual machines to make tests with the Edge legacy browser. [Virtual Machines](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/). You can try to use it and try to produce the issue by using the VM. Let us know the steps if it is possible to reproduce the issue on ourside. We can try to test it.